# PostgreSQL Config File and Query Design for Calculations

Tags: postgresql, config, calculation

I'm new to PG and trying to run this simple query and it's crashing Postgres. The query works in a few seconds if I only try to calculate r1, but says "Out of memory" if I try to calculate r2 through r6 in addition to r1 as below. Poor query design? I'm going to reference the calculated fields r1...r6 in other calculations, so was thinking about making this query a view. My key config file parameters are below. Windows 10, PG 9.6, 40GB RAM, 64-bit. Any ideas on what to do? Thanks!

Edited: I tried adding LIMIT 500 to the end and that worked, but if I run a query on this query, i.e. to use the calculated r1,r2,r3... in another query, will the new query see all the records or will it be limited to just the 500?

```
SELECT
public.psda.price_y1,
public.psda.price_y2,
public.psda.price_y3,
public.psda.price_y4,
public.psda.price_y5,
public.psda.price_y6,
public.psda.price_y7,
(price_y1 - price_y2) / nullif(price_y2, 0) AS r1,
(price_y2 - price_y3) / nullif(price_y3, 0) AS r2,
(price_y3 - price_y4) / nullif(price_y4, 0) AS r3,
(price_y4 - price_y5) / nullif(price_y5, 0) AS r4,
(price_y5 - price_y6) / nullif(price_y6, 0) AS r5,
(price_y6 - price_y7) / nullif(price_y7, 0) AS r6
FROM
public.psda
```

My config file parameters:

```
max_connections = 50
shared_buffers = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 20GB
work_mem = 400MB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
wal_buffers = 16MB
max_wal_size = 2GB
min_wal_size = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
default_statistics_target = 100
```

Comment: Maybe related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478031/error-out-of-memory-on-machine-with-32gb-ram-and-without-swap-file

Comment: Is `public.psda` definitely a table, or is it a view?

Comment: @DavidAldridge it is definitely a table. I moved on to another project, but I will be back to this one soon.

Answer (score 1):

use this service http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/

when calc `total RAM for PostgreSQL` = `total RAM` - `RAM for OS`

PGTune calculate configuration for PostgreSQL based on the maximum performance for a given hardware configuration.

It isn't a silver bullet for the optimization settings of PostgreSQL.

Many settings depend not only on the hardware configuration, but also on the size of the database, the number of clients and the complexity of queries, so that optimally configure the database can only be given all these parameters.